# array.some and others not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, manjaro

On my linux OS i was trying to write javascript code but certain Array functions would raise

```
console.log([false].every())
                    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

i first noticed this when working on a Vuejs (cli) project. But then i tested a simple .js script and ran it with:

```
node test.js
```

the code:

```
console.log('testing')
console.log([])
console.log([false].every)
console.log([false].every())
```

everything works until i call the function in line 4. When logging the funtion on line 3 it logs

```
[Function: every]
```

so this problem seems to be with node since some functions work like map
i'd appreciate any help with how i could fix my nodejs.

.some() also doesn't work i don't know if there are any others

SOLVED: stupid me was so sure he knew how to use the function my bad, thanks alot

Comment: You *must* pass a parameter to `.every` when you invoke it.

Comment: [ECMAScript 2015: 22.1.3.5 `Array.prototype.every ( callbackfn [ , thisArg] )`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.every): _"`callbackfn` **should** be a function that accepts three arguments and returns a value that is coercible to the Boolean value `true` or `false`."_

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function` means that `every` attribute of array is not a function or not a callable, since it's `undefined`. Check the version of nodejs, execute: `node --version` I'm sure it's less than ~5.x.x.  Check this table: https://node.green/

Comment: @num8er No it does not mean that. The error message for that case would be similar to `every is not a function of array`. The problem is the missing callback.

Comment: @str oh You're right.  and Andreas has correct point, it requires callback method as first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not passed function that being executed during array walk that should return boolean result.

From manual (read carefully and see **bold words**):

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented **by the provided function**.

And this is example of correct usage:

```js
let isValidArrayOfIntegers;

isValidArrayOfIntegers = 
  [1, 2, 3, 5.3, 0.1, false, true, NaN, undefined]
    .every(function(item) {
      return Number.isInteger(item);
    });
    
console.log(isValidArrayOfIntegers);


isValidArrayOfIntegers = 
  [1, 2, 3]
    .every(function(item) {
      return Number.isInteger(item);
    });
    
console.log(isValidArrayOfIntegers);
```

P.S. `every` is shorthand to `find` method. Difference is that `find` finds first occurrence, stops iteration and returns valid element. But `every` finds first non valid occurrence and stops iteration with boolean result.

```js
let isValidArrayOfIntegers;

isValidArrayOfIntegers = 
      ![1, 2, 3, 0.1, 5.3, false, true]
        .find(function(item) {
          let isInteger = Number.isInteger(item);
          if (!isInteger) console.log(item, 'is not integer, breaking loop');
          return !isInteger;
        });
        
console.log(isValidArrayOfIntegers);

isValidArrayOfIntegers = 
      ![1, 2, 3]
        .find(function(item) {
          return !Number.isInteger(item);
        });
        
console.log(isValidArrayOfIntegers);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `every` function has one parameter that is required.

The parameter should be a function that will run on each element in the array.

For more info about it read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Just a side note: MDN is *not* the official specification for JavaScript but it is officially supported by most browser vendors and is the best resource to learn about these basics. The official specification is the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/). That is mainly targeted to browser vendors though and might be hard to understand for beginners. Thus MDN is the de-facto standard reference for JavaScript and related web technologies.

Comment: @str Indeed, the official specs would be as useful as a chocolate teapot here, unless you were planning on writing your own browser engine.